# How to prevent rotate text inside div?

Tags: html, css

I have menu something like this [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sc77esdp/), and my question is How can i prevent rotate text inside each div element?

Code :

```
.myClass{
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #aaa;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;

}


.myClass:hover{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}

<div class="myClass">Home</div>
<div class="myClass">Members</div>
<div class="myClass">Pictures</div>
<div class="myClass">Extra</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to rotate 90deg forward and than 90deg backward, instead of 180deg. 
It will look like a 180deg transformation.

Change the color, border, etc. after the first 90deg to have a better visual effect.

Cheers

Comment: Could you add some example? because with your answer i have couple of quetions, how to rotate forward and backward, like this -90deg and than 90deg? in this case my divs disappear

Comment: It disappears, because it is set in an 90deg or -90deg angle.
sorry, it takes to much time to create an example. it is about an CSS animation which starts on :hover instead using a CSS transform. with an animation you can set multiple movements.
please have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp